# Add magic link for Stack Apps

Tags: feature-request, stackapps, magic-links

Comments and chat messages have [shorthand 'magic' links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for all Q&A sites, e.g. typing `[so]` will produce a nicely formatted link: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and `[apple.se]` will produce [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

All Q&A sites? No, I couldn't find a working syntax for [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). Neither `[stackapps]`, `[stackapps.se]` or `[sa]` seem to work. Can it be added please?